# Cannot run a 64-bit JVM in 64-bit Windows 7 with a large heap size

Tags: java, windows, memory-management, 64-bit

This is 64-bit `Windows 7 Enterprise` and 64-bit Java 7:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

This happens using a shell of both `C:\Windows\SystemWOW64\cmd.exe` (which I incorrectly thought was the 64-bit version) **and** with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` (which I have just found out, courtesy of Pulsar, is a 64-bit application despite the path name).

The program itself is trivial:

```
public class Trivial
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("total = " + toMB(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()));
        System.out.println("max   = " + toMB(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()));
    }

    private static long toMB(long bytes) {
        return bytes / (1024L * 1024L);
    }
}
```

I was just fooling around with different `-Xmx` and `-Xms` arguments to see what would happen.  I would have though that with 64-bit Java on 64-bit Windows I could use pretty much whatever size max and initial heap I wanted, but that's not what's happening.

`java -Xmx16G -Xms2G Trivial` (for example) works fine.  However, `java -Xmx16G -Xms4G Trivial` gives me:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Weirder (to me), `java -Xmx16G -Xms3G Trivial` gives a different error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate tables for parallel garbage collection for the requested heap size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Attempting to split the difference between `2G` and `3G` to see if there was a specific size where this happened I tried `java -Xmx16G -Xms2900M Trivial` and it worked.  Then I tried `-Xms2960M` and it worked.  With `-Xms2970m` the JVM crashed:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1048576 bytes for E in C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities/taskqueue.hpp
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\QuantumMechanic\Temp\hs_err_pid10780.log
```

That continued until `-Xms2995M` when it switched back to the "unable to allocate tables for parallel garbage collection" message and stuck with that as `-Xms` was increased further.

What could be going on?  Does launching something from `cmd.exe` (even a 64-bit one) impose some process size limits?  Is Windows (or the JVM) requiring a single huge memory block?  (But then why the different messages)?  Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a 64-bit system, you have 2^63Bytes of user address **space**, but you can still only map the amount of actual memory you have (physical + page file + mapped files).

When the JVM creates the heap, it's using C `malloc()` to request an initial chunk of memory and then it is going to manage the chunk **by itself**. Even if you don't have any object on the heap at all, to the OS the chunk is being used.

Since you specified `-Xms`, which is the minimum value of the memory pool, the JVM will simply try to require that amount of memory from the OS or fail as it can't satisfy your command.

I guess if you want to see the advantage of 64 bit Java. Maybe you can try opening a file larger than 4GB for random access and map it to a MappedByteBuffer.

Comment: A possible swap space limit.  I hadn't thought of that.  When I get back to work tomorrow I'll check the pagefile size settings on that computer and see what it's set to.

Comment: It **was** swap size.  Rather than being auto-managed, for some reason the pagefile on the computer I was using was set to a constant size of 4GB.  The computer's RAM was 8GB, so at best there was 12GB of virtual memory, and of course there were a whole bunch of other programs running.  When I increased the pagefile size I was able to have a much higher `-Xms` value.

Answer (score 5):

SysWoW64 refers to the 32bit `Windows on Windows 64`. Simplified: 32bit windows running on windows 64bit).

So you are explicitly requesting to run in a 32bit cmd shell.

Please see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I never knew that `\Windows\System32` holds 64-bit applications.  However, that's not the problem -- the same thing happens when I use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.