# Grails I can't get testing for scripts working - exit-code always 1

Tags: testing, grails

I found Peter Ledbrook's artice on testing Grails scripts ( http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/testing-your-grails-scripts ). 'Great', I thought, here we go. But I spent ages (without internet access) failing to get it working. I'm using Grails 2.1.1 and GGTS 3.1

I was trying to run his hello-world script. It works when I invoke it as a command. But when I attempt to invoke it from a test class in test\cli, the exit code is always 1. I have added some println statements to the test (and the script). From what I can see, the script never gets invoked (neither do supplied scripts like 'war'). Here is start of my test class:

```
class HelloWorldTests extends AbstractCliTestCase {

void testDefault() {
    println "work dir: "+System.getProperty("grails.home") //cli.work.dir")
    println "about to call script"
    execute(['hello-world']) // Pass parameters in the list
    println "called script"

    int exitCode = waitForProcess()
    println "exit code "+exitCode
    println "output: "+super.getOutput()
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        println output
    }
    assertEquals 0, exitCode
```

The output from the println statements are:

```
work dir: C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\
about to call script
called script
exit code 1
output:
```

From what I could figure out form looking at the code of AbstractCliTestCase, there should be something in 'output', but there isn't.

Help gratefully received

John

Comment: Now that my laptop is network connected, I get something in 'output'. I think I need to set some VM args for the test, but how?

output: Error occurred during initialization of VM

Unable to allocate bit map for parallel garbage collection for the requested heap size.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

BTW: this is Win 7 64 bit with 64 bit GGTS and 64 bit Jdk 1.7.09

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with using a 64 bit JVM. When I changed the runtime config for test-app to use the 32bit version of jdk 1.7.09, my test runs.

References:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7196103
a Java bug says it was fixed in 09-2012. But no indication of which update it is in.

[Java maximum memory on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp/497757#497757)
A discourse on allocation of virtual memory.

[Cannot run a 64-bit JVM in 64-bit Windows 7 with a large heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889081/cannot-run-a-64-bit-jvm-in-64-bit-windows-7-with-a-large-heap-size)
This person solved the problem by increasing his page file form 2 to 4 Gb. I tried that, rebooted, but no difference.

Maybe the answer for now is to have test-app use 32 bit Java, or maybe if I  can force an update to 1.7.09 (if one exists), then that might have the above fix.