# 'Could not reserve enough space for object heap' when running java -version

Tags: java, memory, windows-server-2008, virtual-memory

I know this is a common question/problem. I'm wondering where to get started with it.

Running java on windows server 2008, we have 65GB memory, and it shows 25GB free. (Currently a couple of guys are running processes).

`systeminfo | grep -i memory`

shows:

```
Total Physical Memory: 65, 536 MB
Available Physical Memory: 26,512MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size 69,630 MB
Virtual Memory: Available 299 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use: 69, 331 MB.
```

Really just wondering how I go about solving this problem.

- Where do I start?
- What does it mean that more virtual memory is being
  used than physical memory, and is this why java won't start?
- Does
  java want to use virtual memory rather than physical memory?

`java -version`

gives me:

`Error occured during initialization of VM
could not reserve enough space for object heap`

More specific questions:

- **Why doesn't the JVM want to use the free phsyical memory?**
- **How much memory does a java command (like `java -version`) want to use if you don't specify Xms parameters?**
- **Would simply assigning more virtual memory be a good solution to the problem?**

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit VM or a 32-bit VM?

Comment: `java -version` for the bits. Also, what is your initial heap currently set to?

Comment: I can't do `java -version` it gives me the space error. 

(What's actually happening when I call `java -version`? Is it creating a JVM and then finding out what version it is from that JVM?). 

Not sure what you mean by initial heap, and how would I find out?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for

Comment: using `java -Xms64m -Xmx64m -version` I get
`java version "1.7.0_07"
SE Runtime envrionment <build 1.7.0_07-b10>
Java HotSpot 64-bit server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: The `-Xms64m` in the above is your initial heap setting. You'll get the error you described if this exceeds available memory. I'm not sure of the details, but I believe the memory must be contiguous, too.

Comment: So the question I have, is why doesn't java want to use the physical memory that's available? 
For example at the moment it's showing 29gB available physical memory, and 8gB available virtual memory. 
`java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -version` will work, but `java -Xms16g -Xmx16g -version` will give me the space error. Why won't it use that physical memory?

Comment: So I wrote this question right at the start of my career - like first month on the job. Seven years later and I have this kind of thing is no way near what I do and I find it amazing that  a graduate developer was getting into this and doing ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered when I had a similar problem (though with a lot less memory on the system -- see [Cannot run a 64-bit JVM in 64-bit Windows 7 with a large heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889081/cannot-run-a-64-bit-jvm-in-64-bit-windows-7-with-a-large-heap-size)), on Windows the JVM will try to allocate a *contiguous* block of memory.

So my bet is that while you have enough *total* memory, you don't have enough *contiguous* memory.

Comment: What does it matter if the memory isn't contiguous?
Would it be possible to tell java not to look for contiguous memory?

Comment: It matters because that's what the JVM wants.  It attempts to allocate the memory all-or-none.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/497961/411393 for example as to why the JVM wants contiguous memory (which also implies there's no way to tell it not to require it).

Comment: Okay, so what do I do to ensure memory is contiguous?  I've got plenty of it in the system.  Also, I thought with virtual memory computers a program is presented with a virtual contiguous block of memory and the program doesn't get to know (or care) whether the real memory is contiguous or not.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. From the analysis, we found that the machine have low swap space. 
Please increase the swap space and verify.

Answer (score 0):

At least to see java version run
java -Xmx64m -version
this should show you the version if needed. Then you can try increasing Xmx and see at what value it fails